# Number of moves to type number?

Tags: string, algorithm, implementation, digits

To clarify, both S and D are input here. I want to find the number of moves it takes to type out D.

---

Say I have a string S that represents a 3 by 3 numerical typepad on a phone i.e. if S is "918726534", then it's going to be:

9 1 8

7 2 6

5 3 4

Then given a string of digits, call it D, what's the number of moves it takes to type out D? Assume:

- We start on the typepad at the first digit of D i.e. if D[0] = "1", then we get to start on the 1 key of the typepad for free.
- It takes 1 move to move to an adjacent key on the typepad (diagonal moves allowed). No wrapping around (a la Pac-Man) allowed.
- It takes 0 moves to press a number on the typepad.

Here are my thoughts so far on the problem. For a function that tells you the "distance" between two consecutive digits in D (or any string), you only have to enumerate (9 choose 2) + 9 = 45 possibilities since that's the number of pairs. And clearly the 9 corresponds to moving from x to x where the "distance" is 0. So it's more like only (9 choose 2) = 36 possibilities. However, I'm stuck on how to proceed further. Any help would be well-appreciated.

---

**Update:** Including an example per Ulrich Eckhardt's suggestion in the comments.

Say S is "918726534" i.e. corresponding to typepad:

9 1 8

7 2 6

5 3 4

And say D is "1527339".

- 1 to 5: Takes 2 moves.
- 5 to 2: Takes 1 move.
- 2 to 7: Takes 1 move.
- 7 to 3: Takes 1 move.
- 3 to 3: Takes 0 moves.
- 3 to 9: Takes 2 moves.

Hence the number of moves it takes to type out D in this instance is 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 2 = 7.

Comment: Are you supposed to find the optimal string `S`, or is `S` and input to your code?

Comment: Thanks @user3386109, I've updated my question to clarify that S is input in addition to D.

Comment: Can you give an example for a string `D` and the moves it takes? I'd say the minimum number of moves is zero for any number that only consists of one digit. For a general solution, I'd prepare a graph where the edges between vertices carry the number of moves. I'd then go through that graph acording to the input digits and count the number of moves along the edges. BTW: Why "minimum" number of moves? Why not "the" number of moves instead?

Comment: Note that the distance between digits can only be 1 or 2. Use `D` to fill a 3x3 array. Then you can easily find the distance from a digit `a` to another digit `b`. If `b` is next to `a`, the distance is 1. Otherwise the distance is 2.  Use that information to fill a 10x10 matrix so that you can easily look up the distance for any pair of digits.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between any two numbers will in range `[0,2]`, where

```
dist(i, j) = 
0 if i == j
1 if isAdjacent(i, j) = True
2 for other cases
```

For calculating `isAdjacent(i, j)`, you can easily precompute and store the results in a 2D array. With that out of the way, the algorithm becomes pretty simple:

```
ans = 0
for index in range [1,n]:
    x = number[index], y = number[index - 1]
    if x == y: continue
    else if isAdjacent(x, y): ans += 1
    else: ans += 2

return ans
```